# Using Scanner to change boolean in java

Tags: java

This is my first post here, so I decided to browse around various posts here in order to try and get a feel for how questions should be posted.

Hence, if I mess up please let me know so I can fix my post accordingly ASAP.

So here is my problem:

I started learning Java today and I'm working on just getting a feel for how everything works. I have the code below set to tell if kids are good or bad and display corresponding replays.

Good kids get candy, bad kids get none. I want to be able to limit the users choices to good or bad and have their answer change the `Boolean` to `true` or `false` to run the right `if` statement.

I saw a `Math.random` way of doing it but when I tried it I got more problems.

Thank you for your time.

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        //take user info 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int candy = 12;
        int kids = 4;
        int bad = 1;
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        int answer = candy / kids;
        String answer2 = "No Candy";
        boolean good = false;

        System.out.println(a);
        //closeing the scanner
        sc.close();

        if(bad == 1) {
            System.out.println(answer2);
        } else {
            if(bad == 2)
                good = true;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
        if(good == true) {
            System.out.println("Good Job");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again tomorrow!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you want to do here.  Can you state exactly what the expected output is for each input?

Comment: I think the confusing part it the random math it dose. This code is my first code ever so I'm more or less using one class to test different concepts and see what I an do with what I learned in the last 3 hours or so. If you take out the random math the code would (at least what I'm now trying to do) ask user how many kids there are, if they have been good or bad then display a message saying good kids get candy and bad kids do not. The math done divides candy by kids. 

Currently if you change the value of 

    int bad = 1;

to 2 it will run the Try again tomorrow statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, it is not necessary to end the scanner before your code ends. You can leave it around, closing it is not necessary. (Unless your IDE forces you to , then yes, you should, but close it at the end just in case. I have Eclipse, so my code still runs without a glitch.)

Another comment is, just for the sake of aesthetics you should concatenate some kind of string on to the end of `answer`, so the reader understands what the variable means.

One more thing. I often find it helpful to name my scanner something a little more intuitive, such as input. Because after all, that's what it is. (I'm only commenting a lot about your code because you are just beginning to learn things, so you should get into good habits early.)

What you can do in this situation is convert your string inputs to booleans, by using `boolean userInput = Boolean.parseBoolean(answer)`. Then, depending on the input the user gives by using an if statement, they can control the flow of the code.

I cleaned up your code a little bit, if you don't mind.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lol {
    public static void main (String args[]){
    //take user info 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    int candy = 12;
    int kids = 4;
    int answer = candy / kids;
    String answer2 = "No Candy";

    System.out.println("Are youkids good or bad?");
    System.out.println("[1] Good = true");
    System.out.println("[2] Bad = false");
    String a = sc.nextLine();
    boolean userInput = Boolean.parseBoolean(a);

    if(userInput== false){
        System.out.println(answer2);
        System.out.println("Try again tomorrow!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Good Job");
        System.out.println("You get" +answer+"pieces.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @joe jones Welcome to Java and Stack Overflow, my friend.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've been a little worried about self teaching because I don't want to have bad coding habits. So thank you so so so much for that advice. 

So I've learned about the Integer.parseInt(); but being new at this didn't know that there was a Boolean version. 

All ready made a random number generator that you take a guess from 1-10 and the computer compares its number (using Math.floor( Math.random() ) against yours  and tells you if you guessed right. Thus making me want to take user input for good and bad kids and then try and add math to the code to see if i could.

Comment: No problem. If you want resources, you should stick to a single textbook, it will really help in future. Personally, I've had a few classes myself, but I recommend "Introduction to Java Programming" by Y. Daniel Liang. Additionally, I use a website called codingbat.com, which has a lot of exercises with Java. And finally, once you get a little more proficient, there is a website called projecteuler.com that uses a lot of math and a lot of loops, if that's your thing. Self-teaching is really difficult, but if you stay dedicated it definitely pays off. Websites like this will also help you.

Comment: Alright, I booked marked the two sites however the book is out of my price range. I compeltly again self teaching is crazy hard, worst part is not being able to ask someone a question face to face. Thank god I came across this site.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're just starting out, I'll try and keep it simple. There are plenty of ways to force your reader to say either "good" or "bad" that are better than below, but they require loops (which I assume you haven't touched yet).

Consider the following:

```
boolean good = false;
if (a.equals("good")) { // they said good
    good = true;
} else if (a.equals("bad")) { // they said bad
    good = false;
} else { // they said neither
    System.out.println("You didn't say a correct word!");
}
```

You first specify that you have a `boolean good` (which you can either give a default value as above, or nothing). Then, depending on the user's input, you can set the boolean to be whatever is appropriate.

The reasoning behind having to declare the `boolean good` above the if statements has to do with the scope of a variable. If your book/teacher hasn't explained what that is, you should look it up now. The TL;DR is that if you only first declare your variable inside the if statements, then it will disappear as soon as you leave the if statements. You can see how in this case that would basically defeat the purpose of the if statements entirely.

Comment: I don't have anyone teaching me, I'm using random websites to learn so I'm having a hard time finding content that follows a set path from start to finish but I am mostly getting basics I feel. 

So my use of 2 different if/else statments is unneeded and could be shortened with your example of else if? (Have not seen else if yet, I'm assuming its just another iteration of "if" before the last else)

I was unaware that Boolean could be left empty I thought they had to be true or false to start so thats amazing to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the input by enclosing it in a loop.

```
List<String> accepted = new ArrayList<String>();
accepted.add("good");
accepted.add("bad");

System.out.println("Good or bad?");
String input = sc.nextLine();
while(!accepted.contains(input)) {
   System.out.println("Invalid query '" + input + "'. Try again.");
   input = sc.nextLine();
}
```

The code you have, well I don't know exactly what it's trying to do. It doesn't look functional at all. So where this fits in I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Did you really just introduce lists and loops to someone who says that this is their first day of learning JAVA?

Comment: Did I really just introduce two very simple constructs that every person who ever codes in Java needs to know how to use? Why yes, yes I did. It's simple: if you want to get a proper input, you have to use a loop. And yes, I used a list instead of an array, but OP is already using Scanner which is significantly more complicated than List... Like, honestly, this code is so simple it actually reads like English!!

Comment: I have not come to the point of learning about arrays yet. I think its coming up. this is just code Im working on the make sure I understand the concept of coding over all. I don't really have an over all goal with the code so there is no clear objective to the code. Just making sure that I can get an if statement to work or getting the Scanner thing to import. 



Thank you for your help :>


ps. "Like, honestly, this code is so simple it actually reads like English!!" HAHAHAHAHAH! omg that's amazing

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class app {

public static void main (String args[]){
    //take user info 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a="?";

    while(!a.equals("good") && !a.equals("bad")){
        System.out.println("Was the kid good or bad ?");
        a = sc.nextLine();
    }

    boolean wasKidGood = a.equals("good");
    String result = (wasKidGood ? "Good kid gets candy" : "No candy for bad kid");
    System.out.println(result);
    sc.close();
    }
}
```

Hello, I wrote something, that will help you grasp a while loop and a ternary operator (alternative version of if loop). You also need to pay attention as to where you are allowed to use == and where you should use the equals() method. Regards